# Does a Monk gain benefits from taking a level in Fighter and choosing Unarmed Fighting from Tasha's?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, multi-classing, unarmed-combat, fighting-style

The Unarmed Fighting style from Tasha's states:

> Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier. If you strike
> with two free hands, the d6 becomes a d8.  When you successfully start a grapple, you can deal 1d4
> bludgeoning damage to the grappled creature. Until the grapple ends, you can also deal this damage to
> the creature whenever you hit it with a melee attack.

Would a, say, 2nd-level Monk gain a benefit from taking a single level in Fighter, making unarmed strikes with a d8+STR?
This seems better than the 1d4 from the early levels.

Comment: Just a mention, the monk could do D8+dexterity if unarmed if they choose, not just D8+str

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This works, but it becomes mostly redundant at higher levels.

You have the right of it - by taking this fighting style, you can use a d6 (or d8) for your unarmed strikes at the lower levels of monk before your martial arts die matures. Your martial arts die becomes d6 at 5th level monk and d8 at 11th level monk, so the fighting style loses some of its utility at each of these levels.

In my estimation, *this is not worth a 1 level multiclass dip*.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning it's better to just take Minotaur as a race from the Storm Coast, as it gets a 1d6 + Strength unarmed weapon *and* a basic Charger * Shield Master feat to use with it's horns, requiring no multi-classing at all.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli We'd prefer it if you didn't share links to sites which illegally host paid content.

Comment: My bad, thanks for stripping it. I just fired Minotaur race 5e at google and linked for reference to the stats. Here's a source from Wizards instead: https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli It is worth noting that the officially published minotaur dropped the hybrid nature trait possessed by the UA version.

Comment: Yep, but since I couldn't find a released version by Wizards, that's the closest official one I could link without the reference being stripped. LOL. ;)

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps a little consideration on the side: Tasha's allows swapping out skills if your DM agrees, so you could - if you wanted to - take 1 level in fighter for the d6/d8 unarmed strikes (and the Second Wind), and when you reach 11th level in monk, you could ask your DM to switch to a different fighting style (perhaps Superior Technique). Of course it would be best to clear that with the DM before you take the Fighter level...